# IIS vs. localhost Context.User.IsInRole()

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-authentication

Using this code I made to simplify my problem:

```
<%@ Page Language="c#" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <title>Am I me</title>
        <script language="c#" runat="server">
        private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {

            Label2.Text = "I am " + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            bool result = Context.User.IsInRole(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
            Label1.Text = "Am I me? " + result;
            result = HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
            Label1.Text += "                   Am I myself now? " + result;

        }
        </script>
    </HEAD>
    <body>
        <form id="Form1" runat="server">
            <div>       
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

            </div>
            <div>

                <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="280px"></asp:Label>
           </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

When I runs this code locally it works fine:

[image: LocalHost Image]

But when I run it on our IIS server:

[image: IIS Server]

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

I am using windows-authentiation on intranet sites to clarify. Also the usernames on both match.

Comment: You probably needs to make some adjustments on the web.config, maybe the cookie name/domain

Comment: @Aristos I'm not using any cookies on this page. Parts of web.config that might affect it? `<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true"/> <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" buffer="true" enableEventValidation="true" viewStateEncryptionMode="Always" enableViewStateMac="true"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You are asking if the user is in a Windows group that happens to have the same name as the user.

From the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs485fwh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `IsInRole`:

> Determines whether the current principal belongs to the Windows user
>   group with the specified name.

I suspect the reason it works on your local machine is that you happen to have a group with the same name as your user and your user is also a member of this group.

Comment: I am using the same machine and username to login to both sites though. My username even the 'local ' one are attached to the domain so all the groups I am a member of are the same.

Comment: Yes, but one site appears to be the visual studio hosting process while the other is IIS. Comparing the behavior, especially with respect to security, in these two applications is not a safe bet (the Visual Studio hosting app runs as the current user and IIS runs as the user defined in the app pool).